# MKReverseGeocoder inside of NSThread

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mkreversegeocoder

I have object that implements MKReverseGeocoder. I'm running it inside of separate thread and it is delegate of itself. However its 'didFailWithError' and 'didFindPlacemark' methods are not being called. If i get it outside of thread, than everything works as expected.

Comment: Found a solution to this problem in my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993924/delegate-callback-from-other-nsthread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe MKReverseGeocoder requires a [run loop](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html) to run correctly. If you're using NSThread you'll have to run the run loop manually.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me a short example before i go over the link?

Comment: It will probably be as simple as calling `[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] run]` after starting your geocoder. You might also need to use `-runUntilDate:`. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149646/best-way-to-make-nsrunloop-wait-for-a-flag-to-be-set) also has some good information.